# Cronjob to check and restart service if dead

Tags: linux, bash, centos, cron

I want a 1 liner that can check and restart services, such as Apache if they are inactive/dead.

I want to put it in crontab and run it every minute to make sure the service is still running.

Comment: Don't. Use a monitoring tool (like `monit` or `supervisord` or `runit` or `systemd` or any of the handful of others).

Comment: @EtanReisner systemd has watchdog support (restart service if alive-ping is not send to systemd), but it does not restart the service if a check-service-alive-script fails:: https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2016-May/036683.html "That's out of the scope for systemd really. That's monitoring, and I
am not convinced having custom check function support in systemd is
really appropriate, this should be implemented outside of systemd
really."

Comment: @guettli Interesting. That seems like an awfully small hair to be splitting to me but <shrug>.

Comment: @EtanReisner please elaborate. I can only guess what you mean - I don't like guessing :-)

Comment: @guettli I meant the claim that there's a meaningful difference between restarting on "alive" failure (and other exits) and on other (check-based) conditions. Yes, there's a difference but if (as according to the next post in the thread) "[a]dministrators usually create type timer units" to do this sort or monitoring then clearly they see it as a need that could easily get built in. (But I'm not a systemd dev so my opinion doesn't really matter.)

Answer (score 14):

Sorry for waking up a sleeping thread, but as many of the answers no-longer work and I found this page while looking, I figured I'd add my solution here:

Create script `check_service.sh` and set `SERVICENAME` as desired:

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVICENAME="WHATEVER_SERVICE_YOU_WANT"

systemctl is-active --quiet $SERVICENAME
STATUS=$? # return value is 0 if running

if [[ "$STATUS" -ne "0" ]]; then
        echo "Service '$SERVICENAME' is not curently running... Starting now..."
        service $SERVICENAME start
fi
```

Make the script executable:

```
chmod +x check_service.sh
```

Finally, add the script to Root's crontab by running `sudo crontab -e`:

```
# min   hour    day month   dow cmd
*/1 *   *   *   *   /full/path/to/check_service.sh
```

Save the crontab, and wait patiently!

Comment: Hello, I am looking for similar solution. I wanted to know if this solution works for BusyBox as init system? Or is this for systemd?

Comment: This is for systemd, but you could convert it to work with init, or, you could use one of the older init answers already in this thread.

Answer (score 5):

service_ck.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
STATUS=$(/etc/init.d/service_name status)
# Most services will return something like "OK" if they are in fact "OK"
test "$STATUS" = "expected_value" || /etc/init.d/service_name restart
```

Change file permissions:

```
chmod +x service_ck.sh
```

Update your crontab:

```
# min   hour    day month   dow cmd
*/1 *   *   *   *   /path/to/service_ck.sh
```

Comment: `/etc/init.d/` will sooner or later disappear.

Comment: That's true, but currently `systemd` maps `init.d` to its services pretty well and until it will completely replace `sysv`, `init.d` `start`/`stop` scripts will and should live and thrive.

Comment: @NarūnasK should live and thrive *for a limited lifespan until depreciated  modes/paths/methods are no longer supported*. Also, there is this: `something.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install`. Technically, although its familiar and backward compat, it's confusing and fragmented on modern installs -- not symlinked in a systemd way, don't show up in the right lists/places, etc. BTW you don't need this script/cron at all if you use systemd built in auto-restart abilities: `Restart=always` which should be available on pretty much every distro from here on out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use special software like `monit` for this case. It can check your daemons , restart it if needed and send you alerts. Another good option -- it can *stop* try to restart service after N fails (for example if service cannot start).

Comment: Looks like something vety usefull, but it will be very nice if you provide some manuals or documentation for this `monit` tool. Could you please add some links? Because I tryed to find something myself, but didn't succeed.

Comment: Is this solution useful for you? **luciusodio** and **Seva Kobylin**

Answer (score 1):

If you save this as a bash script it will be a one-liner that you can call from cron. This will restart Apache if it's not in the process list returned by pgrep.

Obviously this assumes that you have pgrep. Adjust your command to restart accordingly.

If Apache is running but not responsive, that is a different issue. You'd have to check that some endpoint is responding (and responding correctly) within a specified timeout, etc.

```
#!/bin/bash

RESTART="/etc/init.d/httpd restart"
PGREP="/usr/bin/pgrep"
HTTPD="httpd"

$PGREP ${HTTPD}

if [ $? -ne 0 ] # if apache not running 
then
 # restart apache
 $RESTART
fi
```

Comment: `/etc/init.d/` will sooner or later disappear.